# Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $X$ be a torsion module over $R$. Then $Tor_n(X,Y)$ is a torsion module for every $n≥0$.

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $X$ be a torsion module over
> $R$. Then $Tor_n(X,Y)$ is a torsion module for every $n≥0$.

I attempted proving this fact using the definition of what it means to be a torsion module and the definition of $Tor_n(X,Y)$ using a projective resolution of $X$, but it doesn't come easily due to the difference in dimensions. How should this fact be shown?

Answer (score 2):

Take a projective resolution of $Y$. Then, tensoring with $X$ yields only torsion modules and thus the subquotients (in particular, the homology groups of the complex, aka the various $\mathrm{Tor}$ modules) are still torsion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wonder how we get the two facts that :
1) tensoring with X yields only torsion modules and,
2) the subquotients of it are still torsion

Comment: It depends on what your exact definition for “torsion module” is, but 1) should follow from the definition of the tensor product and 2) by standard commutative algebra.